# InetAddress getLocalHost() does not return expected IP address from C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

Tags: java, networking, ip-address, localhost, inetaddress

In the file **C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts** I have only the following line

```
192.168.0.23    computername.domain.com   computername
```

When I run

```
InetAddress localhost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
System.out.println("getLocalHost:" + localhost);
```

I would expect the output to be

```
getLocalHost:computername/192.168.0.23
```

but it comes out as

```
getLocalHost:computername/192.168.0.107
```

Any ideas on why this happens? Should the configuration be made in some other file (too)?

EDIT

```
InetAddress.getByName('computername')
```

produces the same IP as `getLocalHost()` does.

Comment: Why would you expect the entry from the hosts file to affect the IP address for localhost? I'd expect if you do a InetAddress.getByName('computername'), that would give you the IP address you want.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`getLocalHost()` returns the actual IP of one of your network adapters. If you do ipconfig in your command line one of your adapters should return the same address.

If you have multiple adapters and want a specific one, you will need to use `NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()` and then pull the list of InetAddresses from each interface.

Comment: Yep, in general `InetAddress.getLocalHost()` should be avoided. People simply have to realize that the answer from that method only HAPPENS to give the result you expect. Scenario: Your app has worked fine for years. Then you move it to a multi-homed host and bang! It stops working as you expect. Morale: don't rely on `InetAddress.getLocalHost()` for anything but textual info. I've upvoted this answer.

Answer (score 4):

Why would entries from the `hosts` file affect the IP address for `localhost`?

`InetAddress.getByName('computername')` should give you the IP address you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but nope, it gives the same one as getLocalHost()

Comment: It may, but may not. Hosts file is not the only, and not always the main source of name-to-address mapping. Under windows you have DNS and WINS, at least.

Comment: On Windows, I believe the hosts file entry will be the first thing looked up for name resolution, which is why most anti-malware software will add a loopback address mapping for known malware serving hosts in the hosts file, thus preventing browsing to that domain name. [Not definitive but the first source I found].(http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/hosts.htm)